# How do you edit cpu particles velocity in code

Tags: godot

```
extends CPUParticles2D

    func _physics_process(_delta):

        self.initial_velocity = (Global.pw)
```

I need the velocity of the particles to scale with the variable but cannot figure out how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you ever used `range_lerp()` function.

check this link on [Range Lerp](https://godotforums.org/d/19957-what-is-range-lerp-what-are-it-s-function)